# Mathematica large table periodic interpolation

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, interpolation

I have a very large table in Mathematica ((dimcub-1)^3 elements) coming from an inverse FFT. I need to use periodic interpolation on this table. Since periodic interpolation requires that the first elements and last elements are equal, I create a new table of dim^3 elements manually and use that in my interpolation. It works but it is ugly/slow and due to my superfluous intermediate table, I hit the memory barrier sooner.  Can any one tell me either how to turn my old table into a periodic one somehow by appending elements or use my non periodic table to make a periodic interpolation function? Here is my current piece of code:

`mr 1` is the new table:

```
mr1 = Table[  0. , {i, 1, dimcub}, {j, 1, dimcub}, {k, 1, dimcub}];

Do[Do[  Do[   
      mr1[[m, n, k]] = oldtable[[m, n, k]] ;  , {m, 1, 
       dimcub - 1}]; , {n, 1, dimcub - 1}]; , {k, 1, dimcub - 1}]; 
Do[Do[     mr1[[m, n, dimcub]] =  mr1[[m, n, 1]]; 
  mr1[[m, dimcub, n]] =  mr1[[m, 1, n]];  
  mr1[[dimcub, m, n]] =  mr1[[1, m, n]];     , {m, 1, dimcub - 1}];  
 mr1[[n, dimcub, dimcub]] =  mr1[[n, 1, 1]]; 
 mr1[[dimcub, n, dimcub]] =  mr1[[1, n, 1]];  
 mr1[[dimcub, dimcub, n]] =  mr1[[1, 1, n]]; , {n, 1, dimcub - 1}]; 
mr1[[dimcub, dimcub, dimcub]] = mr1[[1, 1, 1]]; 

Remove[oldtable]; 

myinterpolatingfunction = 
 ListInterpolation[mr1, {{1, dimcub}, {1, dimcub}, {1, dimcub}}, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 1, 
  PeriodicInterpolation -> True];

 Remove[mr1];
```

`myinterpolatingfunction` takes much less memory and works perfectly once i remove the older tables.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers.  I tried the suggestion by leonid but when I print my oldtable, it was still (dimcub -1)^3 dimensional. New elements were defined and I can see them individually but they do not show up as part of the oldtable when I print the whole table.  So I ended up with something similar which is doing exactly what I needed:

```
oldtable= PadRight[oldtable, {dimcub, dimcub, dimcub}];
oldtable[[All, All, dimcub]] = oldtable[[All, All, 1]];
oldtable[[All, dimcub, All]] = oldtable[[All, 1, All]];
oldtable[[dimcub, All, All]] = oldtable[[1, All, All]];
oldtable[[All, dimcub, dimcub]] = oldtable[[All, 1, 1]];
oldtable[[dimcub, All, dimcub]] = oldtable[[1, All, 1]];
oldtable[[dimcub, dimcub, All]] = oldtable[[1, 1, All]];
oldtable[[dimcub, dimcub, dimcub]] = oldtable[[1, 1, 1]];
```

The answer by Wizard is far too advanced for my level of mathematica..

Comment: I think we all missed the fact that you wanted the new table to be bigger than the old one. See my answer: What held for Leonid's answer also holds for yours: the last four lines are superfluous.

Comment: I wanted the new table bigger than the old one by 1 in each dimension since that is the only way I could have a table with matching end points to feed into periodic listinterpolation. If there is a way to do a periodic interpolation without this intermediate step, I would rather use it.

Comment: could you please modify your solution so as to make periodic only the 2nd and 3rd dimensions and not the 1st? [in my case the last 2 dimensions are spatial coordinates and the first one is time]

Answer (score 10):

Both Leonid's and Mr.Wizard's answers do too much work. In Leonid's case only the first three lines are necessary. To show this I'll change the last 4 `Set`s to `Equal`s:

```
In[65]:= len = 4; oldtable = 
 Partition[Partition[Range[len^3], len], len]

Out[65]= {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 
   16}}, {{17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24}, {25, 26, 27, 28}, {29, 
   30, 31, 32}}, {{33, 34, 35, 36}, {37, 38, 39, 40}, {41, 42, 43, 
   44}, {45, 46, 47, 48}}, {{49, 50, 51, 52}, {53, 54, 55, 56}, {57, 
   58, 59, 60}, {61, 62, 63, 64}}}

In[66]:= oldtable[[All, All, -1]] = oldtable[[All, All, 1]];
oldtable[[All, -1, All]] = oldtable[[All, 1, All]];
oldtable[[-1, All, All]] = oldtable[[1, All, All]];
oldtable[[All, -1, -1]] == oldtable[[All, 1, 1]]
oldtable[[-1, All, -1]] == oldtable[[1, All, 1]]
oldtable[[-1, -1, All]] == oldtable[[1, 1, All]]
oldtable[[-1, -1, -1]] == oldtable[[1, 1, 1]]

Out[69]= True

Out[70]= True

Out[71]= True

Out[72]= True
```

What Leonid does is illustrated in the figures below. Lines 4-6 of his code do something as illustrated in the left-hand panel: copying a line (darker color) of a plane already copied (light colors). Line 7 is illustrated by the right-hand panel. This is a cell to cell copy of diagonally opposing positions, and its operation is not included in any of the first three copy actions separately, but is a result of their successive operation.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the illustration.  I see your point and agree with you. The way Leonid does copying is left over from my original question in which I was creating a redundant copy of the table to increase the size by 1. Getting rid of the redundant intermediary table already saved me enough memory/time.

Comment: @Sjoerd  +1 for the nice and visual analysis.

Comment: @yoda +1 for noticing. Didn't think anyone would  ;-)

Comment: @Sjoerd I didn't know you are from Serbia! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Flag_of_Serbia_and_Montenegro.svg :)

Comment: @belisarius wrong! -1 for using Wikipedia instead of `Tooltip[CountryData[#, "Flag"], #] & /@ CountryData[]`. You were referring to the flag of the now defunct country of Serbia and Montenegro. The current Serbia has quite a different flag and mma knows it! Anyway, it could be both the French and my country's flag but it would need a rotation.

Comment: @Sjoerd HA! Used `CountryData` ... but it was not there! :) When I was attending school, countries lasted longer

Answer (score 8):

You can get it much faster and more memory-efficiently by modifying the original table as follows:

```
oldtable[[All, All, -1]] = oldtable[[All, All, 1]];
oldtable[[All, -1, All]] = oldtable[[All, 1, All]];
oldtable[[-1, All, All]] = oldtable[[1, All, All]];
oldtable[[All, -1, -1]] = oldtable[[All, 1, 1]];
oldtable[[-1, All, -1]] = oldtable[[1, All, 1]];
oldtable[[-1, -1, All]] = oldtable[[1, 1, All]];
oldtable[[-1, -1, -1]] = oldtable[[1, 1, 1]];
```

These assignments replace nested loops and are much faster, plus you don't need memory to store the copy. This is based on an extended vectorized functionality of the [Part](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Part.html) command (array and general expression indexing), particularly vectorized assignments. It also matters to have your numerical array in a [Packed array](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/LinearAlgebraPerformance.html) form, which is often the case.

Comment: Leonid, you are burning up the charts this week.  #78 on StackOverflow!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wow, did not expect that. Thanks for letting me know! But you forgot about @belisarius and @yoda, they are higher in that list.

Comment: They also do not specialize in the mathematica tag.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  Can you clarify? They both have Mathematica tag listed below their avatars in that list (but have aslso other tags - is that what you mean?)

Comment: Yes.  It is far easier to get rep points if you don't answer only Mathematica questions.  Not meaning to detract from their work, but it's true.

Comment: By the way, I sent you an email a couple of days ago.  Did you receive it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see. I am actually #61 right now :). But you are not far behind, and I think you are generally more stable Mathematica top-ranker in that list. Regarding e-mail - if you mean that test one, yes, I got it and I replied to you - did you get my reply? Or did you mean some other e-mail?

Comment: #61!  Most impressive.  I do outrank you on "Quarter" due to sheer persistence, but when you are active, nobody can match you.  I sent you a message with subject: "Timing behavior of Tally and DeleteDuplicates" -- please see if it ended up in a spam file.

Comment: I am not contending anything, but where do you see #61?  If I click on your name, and then under the icon I click "top 0.55% this week" it brings up a list where I still see #78.  Is there another index?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Regarding an e-mail: terribly sorry, somehow missed. I am getting my mathgroup mail there too, must have been inside those (I look through them of course, but could occasionally miss). Just answered - please check your email. Regarding #: When I first saw your comment of #78, I went to the users list (as clicked on Users), then counted my position there and it was indeed 78 ( I did not know that you can click on "top ... this week"). But then I got some upvotes, and when I checked again (for you, incidentally), I found that I moved to #61. The "top..." has not been updated I guess.

Comment: Re: email, no problem.  I've got a funky address that people often ignore. Re: rank, I see.  I do not bother counting the places on the Users page, so I wait for the "League" tables to update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just did not know about the "League" tables, thought counting is the only way :)

Answer (score 5):

Just because I'm a bit of a loon, Leonid's solution can be written as:

```
a = {0, 1}~Tuples~3~SortBy~Tr // Rest;

MapThread[
  (oldtable[[Sequence @@ #]] = oldtable[[Sequence @@ #2]]) &,
  {-a, a} /. 0 -> All
];
```

Comment: +1, less overall typing, so it is easier to extend. I'd give another +1, if I could, for the double Infix construction of `a`.

Comment: +1. I wanted to show the closest corresppondence to the original loop-based solution, since it is easier to understand. Had in mind to add something very similar to what you did, but it was way too late :). Double infix is really nice indeed! But now, you are responsible for the explanation of how this works :).

Comment: @rcollyer thanks!  I use infix a lot, but I usually remove it form my posts because others rarely use it, so I figure it's hard to read.  For me it is actually easier to read, because I know I am looking at a function with two arguments, and because it reads left-to-right in what I find is a logical way.

Comment: @Sjoerd was ready to sleep, and I didn't even bother to try to understand the problem, I just translated Leonid's code.

Comment: @Leonid I was not suggesting this was superior to your post!  As I said, I was being a bit of a loon.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I think, your post is an absolutley necessary addition to this discussion - it is great that you posted this solution.